# Was the 2006 video game Prey's spirit world based on Cherokee beliefs?

Tags: prey-2006

A feature of the 2006 video game [*Prey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2006_video_game)) is that when the main character suffers fatal damage, he enters a spirit world where he can regain health by shooting flying manta-ray-like creatures (shown in the image below).

[image: spirit world and player readying to shoot a bow]

Are these flying creatures derived from anything in Cherokee beliefs or myths, or were they created solely for the game?

Comment: Interesting question. That game was really cool and a lot of fun, in spite of the repetitive environments. Thee gravity and portal effects were out of this world. Not sure about those fish things though; I think it was just made up for the minigame.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prey_(2006_video_game)#Cherokee_culture

Comment: @Valorum the wiki article does not mention the spirit world or the "manta rays".

Comment: @OrganicMarble - Indeed. Hence why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. Since it doesn't "*answer"* the question asked.